# Assert that code gets ran at some point in unit test?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, signals

I have this unit test:

```
func testState() {
    searchController.filter.query = "Missouri"
    searchController.resultsSignal.subscribePast(with: self) { sections in

        if sections.count < 1 { return }
        // Want to test that code at least gets to here at some point
        ...
    }
}
```

And I want to make sure that I at least get past the line `if sections.count < 1 { return }` at some point.

Since it is getting ran when a signal is fired, I don't care if there is a different signal that gets fired at some point, but I do want to make sure that sections.count > 0 at some point in the test.

Is there a way to do this? I was thinking of using a boolean and initializing it to false then setting it to true if `sections.count` was ever more than one, and asserting that the value was true, but this doesn't work unless I do a delay since I am using signals. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [XCTestExpectation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestexpectation) and call `.fulfill` after `sections.count` to notify the test that an asynchronous test has succeeded.

```swift
func testState() {
    let expectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "Should execute")
    searchController.filter.query = "Missouri"
    searchController.resultsSignal.subscribePast(with: self) { sections in

        if sections.count < 1 { return }
        // Want to test that code at least gets to here at some point
        expectation.fulfill()
        ...
    }
    wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 10) // Will fail if .fulfill does not get called within ten seconds
}
```